# Pass an environment variable with quoted string to make

Tags: bash, makefile, quotes

The following command works as expected and throws no erros:

```
$ make SVC_ARGS="-port 80" SVC=server
```

This doesn't work:

```
$ MAKE_PARAMS=" SVC_ARGS='-port 80' SVC=server "
$ make $MAKE_PARAMS
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
make: *** No rule to make target '80"'. Stop.
```

I've tried to use single quotes and escaped double quotes for `SVC_ARGS`, same error.

Using an environment variable to pass parameters to `make` works fine as long as none of the parameters need quotes.

Basically, I need to find a way to pass a single environment variable to `make` that will be expanded to a list of parameters, some of which may contain quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Two options here to handle variables that should be split into multiple parameters:

Force quote evaluations using the eval

```
MAKE_PARAMS=" SVC_ARGS='-port 80' SVC=server "
eval make $MAKE_PARAMS
```

OR, use an array variables to store the various options:

```
MAKE_PARAMS=(SVC_ARGS='-port 80' SVC=server)
make "${MAKE_PARAMS[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

`$ MAKE_PARAMS=" SVC_ARGS='-port 80' SVC=server "`
`$ make $MAKE_PARAMS`

When you create the `MAKE_PARAMS` variable, you add a space, but on the second line you add a space before you use the `MAKE_PARAMS` variable, this would be a double space in total. Maybe create both parameters separately.

`SVC_ARGS='-port 80'`
`SVC=server "`

`make $SVC_ARGS $SVC`

The `SVC_ARGS` could be in speech marks.